# Mostrar 2 columnas dentro de row. Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, grid

Resulta que tengo el siguiente codigo (esta recortado para que no se tan grande)

**CODIGO DONDE MUESTRO 2 DATOS EN COLUMNAS**

```
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="subida">
                        <form action="subirData" method="post">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group"> //PRIMERA COLUMNA
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control fechaIngreso" name="fechaIngreso">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group"> //SEGUNDA COLUMNA
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control fechaIngreso" name="fechaIngreso">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Placa</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control placa" name="placa">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input id="submit-all" type="submit" value="Subir" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Cuando veo el resultado queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los 2 ultimos input me gustaria que quedaran en donde esta el cuadro rojo, como en este ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que esta mal en el codigo (no se si mal acomodado o no se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asumo que estás usando la última versión de bootstrap 4.3.1, sí es así debes envolver  tus columnas dentro de un div con la clase .form-row

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Formulario</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="subida">
                        <form action="subirData" method="post">
                            <div class="form-row"><!-- agregar esto -->
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <!--//PRIMERA COLUMNA -->
                                    <div class="form-group form-row"> <!-- agregar esto -->
                                        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control fechaIngreso" name="fechaIngreso">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <!--//SEGUNDA COLUMNA -->
                                    <div class="form-group form-row"><!-- agregar esto -->
                                        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control fechaIngreso" name="fechaIngreso">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-row"> <!-- agregar esto -->
                                        <label for="" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Placa</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control placa" name="placa">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input id="submit-all" type="submit" value="Subir" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Puedes consultar la documentación [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#form-grid)

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar el elemento padre: `form-row` y sus hijos `col`, para segmentar mejor el `form` ,de esta manera:

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="subida">
                <form class="" action="subirData" method="post">
                    <div class="form-row"> 
                        <div class="col form-group">
                            <label for="" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control fechaIngreso" name="fechaIngreso">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control fechaIngreso" name="fechaIngreso">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Placa</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control placa" name="placa">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <input id="submit-all" type="submit" value="Subir" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```